# Select Query always runs into RuntimeException

Tags: scala, orm, squeryl

I always run into RuntimeException when i invoke following query:

```
val app = from(appTable)(app => where (app.id === application_ID)
      select(app)).single
```

This query always throws a RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: next called with no rows available
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`single` means that you expect one and only one result of query. If resultset is empty you receive this exception. Use `headOption` method instead of `single`.

Comment: I thought i'll get a 'NoSuchElementException' if it is None. Well i'll try headOption.

Comment: @kemmer `single` returns record `R` but option of record `Option[R]`.

Comment: Squeryl 0.9.6 also added [`singleOption`](https://github.com/squeryl/squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/Query.scala#L55) which will more closely mimic the behavior of `single`, ie: if more than one rows are returned - `singleOption` will throw an exception, but otherwise return `Some` or `None` if the results contain 1 or 0 rows respectively. `headOption` is probably the safest guard against an exception overall, but wanted to mention the alternative for completeness.